# SwiftUI 3-Column NavigationView crashes when middle removes detail

Tags: swiftui, crash, swiftui-navigationview

I am using NavigationView with three columns: Sidebar, Search & Detail.
When a search result in the middle column is selected on the iPad (where search and detail are displayed side by side) and then disappears from the list due to the search term changing, the app crashes with EXC_BREAKPOINT.

The problem is reproducible with the following simple demo app.

1. Search "table"
2. Select "Table"
3. Search "chair"
4. App crashes

```
//
//  ThreeColumnSearchTestApp.swift
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThreeColumnSearchTestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Sidebar()
            Search()
            Detail()
        }
    }
}

struct Sidebar: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: Search()) {
            Text("List")
        }
    }
}

struct Search: View {
    @StateObject var model = SearchModel()
    @State var searchText = ""
    var body: some View {
        List(model.searchResults, id: \.self) { value in
            NavigationLink(destination: Detail(value: value)) {
                Text(value)
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .onChange(of: searchText) { newValue in
            model.searchResults = model.values.filter({ value in
                value.contains(searchText)
            })
        }
    }
}

class SearchModel: ObservableObject {
    var values = ["Table", "Chair", "Floor"]
    var searchResults = [String]()
}

struct Detail: View {
    var value: String?
    var body: some View {
        Text(value ?? "No Selection")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug? Any workarounds?

PS: I know iOS 16 introduces a new way to do this. I didn't test if the problem occurs there as well, I want to support iOS 15.

Comment: I copied/pasted and ran your code on iPad and iPhone simulators. Both worked without any error or crash. Try checking other structs or files in your Xcode instead. You might miss something around there.

Comment: @tail There are no other structs. Could you try on iPad Simulator in landscape mode? Type "table", select the result, and with the search field still selected, hit 5x backspace and write "chair".

Comment: still no error or crash.

Comment: Cannot reproduce as well. Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5